# gaussian mixture model from mfcc features

Tags: gaussian, mfcc, gmm

I am trying to create a GMM speaker model, using the MFCC features of an audio sample of a speaker. I have 18 dimensional MFCC features, for a particular speaker.

To create a GMM model in Java, I have this GaussianMixture.java class, that requires:

1. double[] componentWeights
2. Matrix[] means
3. Matrix[] covariances

You can refer the class here [GaussianMixture.java](https://gist.github.com/satwickdash/bddb45a48e5e71ef60c087f51093c748)

What I cannot understand is how to provide means and covariances of the MFCC data I have extracted.

Do I have to calculate `means` for each of the 18 dimensions ? If so, what would be the `componentWeights` ?

Please correct if I am being unclear somewhere. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to run [EM algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm), it will estimate the gaussian parameters. Or you can MAP-adapt existing GMM, MAP adaptation requires less data than training but requires pretrained GMM model.

There are many implementations, for example [here](https://github.com/harry1357931/GaussianMixtureModel-EM_Algorithm).

Comment: For multidimensional data, do I have to run the algorithm for each dimension separately ? Or is it done differently so the values in one dimension should affect other dimension ?

Comment: You run algorithm for a sequence of multidimensional vectors. Dimensions affect each other.